# Apple App Store Submission - Demo Account

Tags: ios, app-store, metadata, submission

While App Store Submission, there is a field called **Demo Account**.

In my app, we have Login functionality. But we don't have any production test data's to provide to Apple. Earlier this Demo Account was an optional field, but now it seems to be a mandatory field. Please let me know what needs to be done.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

You could add some data and setup a demo account for them to use, then when submitting chose the 'manual' release option.  So after they approve it you can wipe your production data clean again before releasing it to the app store.